# Multiple key map and partial query

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, key, apache-commons

I search map implementation with multiple key. I know [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html) but it dosen't satisfy me.

I want to be able to pass one key and get all entries which contain the passed key, e.g.

```
MultiKeyMap mkm = new MultiKeyMap();
mkm.put("key1", "key2", "key3", "1");
mkm.put("key1", "key22", "key33", "2");
mkm.put("key12", "key22", "key32", "3");

mkm.get("key1");
```

returns null but in this case I want to get "1" and "2"
My own implementation is not an option. I want to use something which I can trust.

Comment: Rather than MultiKeyMap, I think you want [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html)

Comment: Did you have a look at [guice](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)? I have a little problem with your example - the aforementioned guice-Multimap works only properly when using one key at a time. Not as in your example `mkm.put("key1", "key2", "key3", "1");`. Otherwise I think the MultiMap would work fine - and in the same package you get a whole bunch of other Maps - if you can't find it there you'll not find it anywhere ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think Guava has a Table implementation `Table<Key1,Key2,Value>` where you can do `table.get(key1)` or `table.get(key2)` or `table.get(key1, key2)`. I think it only supports two keys per table, but not sure. Might want to take a look at that.

[Guava Table javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> ls=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ls2=new ArrayList<>();
    ls.add("key3");
    ls.add("1");
    ls.add("key2");
    ls.add("key22");
    ls.add("key33");
    ls.add("2");

    ls2.add("key22");
    ls2.add("key32");
    ls2.add("3");

    map.put("key1",ls);
    map.put("key12", ls2);

    map.get("key1");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can turn the requirement around and put the value multiple times, once for each key, then [Guava's MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) is very nice to use:

```
    Multimap<String, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
    map.put("key1", "1");
    map.put("key2", "1");
    map.put("key3", "1");

    map.put("key1", "2");
    map.put("key22", "2");
    map.put("key33", "2");

    map.put("key12", "3");
    map.put("key22", "3");
    map.put("key32", "3");

    Collection<String> values = map.get("key1");
    System.out.println(values);
```

prints

```
    [2, 1]
```